# How to keep the state of keyboard same of previous activity?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

In my activity I have a list of images and one EditText. When I click the image, I use intent to display image in fullscreen activity. when I press the back button the keyboard does not in the same state. I mean when hide the keyboard it displays on its own. Please help me how to maintain the state of keyboard. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put focus on edit text again when activity resumes again after back press in full screen image view.

Answer (score 1):

save the state of keyboard on a class field boolean. than onresume of the previous actvity you set the keyboard to shown or hidden depending on the saved value.